# IndexError: tuple index out of range when creating exe file for tkinter from pyinstaller

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, exe

I am trying to create a EXE file of my python code but i am getting the error when i run this code. **pyinstaller -F -c main.py**

I tried my best to find a solution, looked all related question but i was not able to get fix, i also tried every yooutube video but i am still getting this error. Please help me out

**Error**

```
    599 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
616 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
5199 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'C:\\Users\\Yasin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-distutils.py'.
5200 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'C:\\Users\\Yasin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib'
6419 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
6579 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
6594 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
6786 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\Yasin\Documents\InstaDudes\main.py
8416 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook site from 'C:\\Users\\Yasin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-site.py'.
8417 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'C:\\Users\\Yasin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
17983 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook urllib3.packages.six.moves from 'C:\\Users\\Yasin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-urllib3.packages.six.moves.py'.
22792 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook six.moves from 'C:\\Users\\Yasin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-six.moves.py'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 124, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 58, in run_build        
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 827, in main 
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 759, in build    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\Documents\InstaDudes\main.spec", line 7, in <module>
    a = Analysis(
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 311, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 155, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 473, in assemble
    priority_scripts.append(self.graph.add_script(script))
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 265, in add_script
    self._top_script_node = super().add_script(pathname)
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1433, in add_script
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2510, in _safe_import_hook
    self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1544, in import_hook
    for target_submodule in self._import_importable_package_submodules(
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1794, in _import_importable_package_submodules
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 387, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2510, in _safe_import_hook
    self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1544, in import_hook
    for target_submodule in self._import_importable_package_submodules(
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1794, in _import_importable_package_submodules
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 387, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2301, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1505, in import_hook
    target_package, target_module_partname = self._find_head_package(
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1684, in _find_head_package
    target_package = self._safe_import_module(
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 387, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2301, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1518, in import_hook
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(head, mname, submodule)
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 387, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2301, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1518, in import_hook
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(head, mname, submodule)
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 387, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2510, in _safe_import_hook
    self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1544, in import_hook
    for target_submodule in self._import_importable_package_submodules(
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1794, in _import_importable_package_submodules
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 387, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2510, in _safe_import_hook
    self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1544, in import_hook
    for target_submodule in self._import_importable_package_submodules(
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", 
    target_package, target_module_partname = self._find_head_package(
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1684, in _find_head_package
    target_package = self._safe_import_module(
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 387, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2301, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1518, in import_hook
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(head, mname, submodule)
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 387, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2061, in _safe_import_module
    n = self._scan_code(module, co, co_ast)
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2645, in _scan_code
    self._scan_bytecode(
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2749, in _scan_bytecode
    for inst in util.iterate_instructions(module_code_object):
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\util.py", line 139, in iterate_instructions
    yield from get_instructions(code_object)
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\dis.py", line 338, in _get_instructions_bytes
    argval, argrepr = _get_const_info(arg, constants)
  File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\dis.py", line 292, in _get_const_info
    argval = const_list[const_index]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

And Here is my Code
**main.py**

```
from tkinter import Entry, messagebox, Tk, Button, Label
from tkinter.font import Font
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from instadude import main


def Error_box():
    messagebox.showerror('Invalid Key', 'Error: Please Enter Valid Key!')

def Error_box_username():
    messagebox.showerror('InstaDude', 'Error: Username Feild Required!')

def Error_box_password():
    messagebox.showerror('InstaDude', 'Error: Password Feild Required!')

def Login_success():
    messagebox.showinfo('InstaDude','Login Succes: Welcome')





def mains():




def validate_key():
    if(username_input.get() == "TEM8S2-" and pass_input.get() == "&=n_" ):
        Login_success()
        root.destroy()
        main()
        
    elif (username_input.get() == ""):
        Error_box_username()
        

    elif (pass_input.get() == ""):
       Error_box_password()

    else:
       Error_box()
root = Tk()
root.title("automation")
root.geometry("1000x600")




bigfont = Font(family="Port Lligat Slab",size=20,weight="bold",slant="roman")
small = Font(family="Port Lligat Slab",size=10,slant="roman")
Text = Label(root,text="Welcome To InstaDude",font=bigfont,bg="#ADF1A5")
Text.grid(row=0,column=1)

Text1 = Label(root,text="Your Personal Instagram Growth Tool",font=small)
Text1.grid(row=1,column=1)

text = Label(root,text="Product Key")
text.grid(row=2,column=1)
username_input = Entry(root,bd=3,width=50)
username_input.grid(row=3,column=1)

passtext = Label(root,text="Password",)
passtext.grid(row=4,column=1)
pass_input = Entry(root,bd=3,width=40,show="*")
pass_input.grid(row=5,column=1)



button = Button(root, text="Validate Key",command=validate_key,bg = "#6CD300", fg = "black")
button.grid(row=6,column=1,)





file = Image.open("hello.png")
file = file.resize((400,400),Image.ANTIALIAS)
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file)
Label(root,image=image).grid(row=7,column=0,padx=10)
hello = Label(root, text="Made with ❤  ",bg="#FFD700", justify="center")
hello.place(relx=0.43,rely=0.95)


root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mains()
```

Comment: What's the exact name of your file?

Comment: I normally use `pyinstaller --noconsole --onefile -i ".../main.py"` when I bulid so maybe that would make a difference but I don't really know

Comment: Its main.py of my  main file name @Swagrim

Comment: @Hippolippo it says pyinstaller: error: the following arguments are required: scriptname

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1832058/furas Can you please help me with this sir

Comment: I can't reproduce this error on Linux Mint using `PyInstaller 4.7` with  `Python 3.10.1` and `Python 3.8.10` - I have no idea what can make problem

Comment: I got the solution , the problem was that image , and image required position , so i just removed that images and it worked